# PHP / Symfony built-in server not handling request correctly (dev env)

Tags: php, symfony, http, symfony4

After a few hours of sleuthing I discovered this error in the logs:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 112 bytes exceeds the
> limit of 50 bytes

Super bizarre, as PHP is configured to `post_max_size` is set to 50MB (this is what phpinfo() tellsd me).

Here is an example of the raw HTTP request contents (according to Symfony profiler):

> comments=THIS%20IS%20A%20TEST&disposition=Awaiting%20Customer%20Response&id_inactive=-1&id_warehouse=1&id_workorder=218204&

Here is what Chrome is telling me it's sending to the server:

```
POST /erp/pause HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8088
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 123
Authorization: Basic YYY
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.59 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:8088
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:8088/erp/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PHPSESSID=XXX
comments: THIS IS A TEST
disposition: Awaiting Customer Response
id_inactive: -1
id_warehouse: 1
id_workorder: 218204
(empty)
```

Symfony has nothing in any of the request objects. I am using the `symfony server:start`

What is going on here? This wasn't an issue previous to switching to PHP built-in server. Most requests work fine (in fact all have so far). Also works fine in production, which is using NGINX.

I am curious if this is due to the XMLHttpRequest? Or is it a PHP CLI configuration issue? I've googled looking for bugs but found nothing.

NOTE | This is a development environment running in Docker, I am not terribly interested in switching back to NGINX for dev, I'd much rather figure out this issue with the CLI built-in server.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you check `symfony local:php:list` if you have multiple php versions available and that you use the right one? Also, can you run `<full path to php> -i | grep post_max_size` to confirm it says `post_max_size => 50M => 50M`? You can get the full path from the the symfony output, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Try to check for the actual value of post_max_size, the way your app is seeing it. I'd say, in your controller, responsible to handle the request, do like this: dump(ini_get('post_max_size')); check its value in your twig profiler and move forward in your debugging from there.

Comment: I've confirmed `post_max_size` is indeed 50MB.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out - was indeed a configuration issue:

https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-164484.htm

TL;DR The php.ini file had used the units `MB` and NOT just `M` as per the docs. I'm guessing the ini parser reads the last suffix of the string, ignoring the `M` and instead seeing `B` which is why I was limited to 50 bytes of post data :o

Super annoying gotcha - hopefully this helps someone :)